# Change verbose_name for is_superuser Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a custom User model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Field `is_superuser` inherited from `PermissionsMixin`. Is there a possibility to change `verbose_name` and `help_text` for `is_superuser` to my own text without changing Django sources?

Comment: You can not override the field? Like: is_superuser = models.BooleanField('your verbose here', default=False,
        help_text='your help text here')?

Comment: @AndersonLima Nope, `manage.py makemigrations` gives error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'is_superuser' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'PermissionsMixin'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit UserChangeForm, then, override superuser verbose and help_text, like this:

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    is_superuser = forms.BooleanField(label='My Verbose', help_text='My Help Text', initial=False, required=False)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
```

Comment: What to write in admin.site.register(?,?) ?